# How to create N number of Input boxes using HTML based on user Input?

Tags: html, flask

I'm taking input N from user.
Now, i want to write a code in HTML Which is able to create N input boxes.

Suppose N=4
Now, How to create 4 input box using html.

N= 1000
Now, How to create 1000 input box using html.

Note: HTML + Flask preferred

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet

```js
       function func(){
            var num = document.getElementById("num").value
            for(i=0 ; i<num ; i++){
                document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML += "<input type='text'><br>";
            }
        }
```

```html
<input type="number" name="" id="num" placeholder="enter number">
    <button onclick="func()">click</button><br><br>
    <div id="inputs"></div>
```